# WooCommerce shows admin details

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've got a problem

Once I go to the checkout page after having added one item or more to my cart, it shows the billing checkout form with already filled inputs. See below:

[image]

It shows my full details, including email and phone number to every possible buyer.

I installed the SendGrid plugin and discovered it, but removing the plugin did not fix the issue.
I cannot see in any WordPress option where I can edit the value of these input boxes to be empty.

Comment: did you try, not being logged in, and a fresh browser? might just be your details

Comment: I tried using different browsers, different computers and different internets (vpn, different wifi etc.).

Comment: weird - I see no reason, that the plugin, should use the admin details as a "placeholder" - did you somehow, in translation of the webpage, translate "firstname" to Marcus, instead of "Fornavn"?

Comment: Also strange, as there are multiple admin accounts, but only mine are shown. I have not put my details in the translation, no.

Comment: Also - SendGrids plugin has horrible reviews? https://wordpress.org/plugins/sendgrid-email-delivery-simplified/#reviews

Comment: I removed it completely and cleared the cache, still happening.

Comment: email which is being displayed is used for Login purpose or the email you entered in SendGrids

Answer (score 0):

Super weird...

one thing you can try, is using a hook to alter the current "default" value of your form

Since I don't know, in what priority the default value is already getting changed, I would start by setting it to 20, and then trying 30, 40 etc.

```
// Hook in - 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_address_fields', 20 );

// Our hooked in function - $address_fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['first_name']['placeholder'] = 'Firstname';

    return $address_fields;
}
```

Hope this works - It was way to long for a comment.